# Results repeat if inserted in more then one category

Tags: mysql

i need some help with a little problem that occurred today.

To show the latest posts in website, i use this script, also this script exclude some categories (my website is not in wordpress,but the db names has wp in front)

```
  SELECT
  ID, 
  post_title, 
  post_content, 
  post_date, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT post_category ORDER BY post_category DESC SEPARATOR ", " ) as "categories"

  FROM 
  wp_posts, 
  wp_term_relationships,
  wp_term_taxonomy 

  WHERE wp_posts.post_status = "publish"    
  AND wp_term_relationships.object_id = id
  AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy= "category"
  AND !(wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = 34472 ||
        wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = 34473 ||
        wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = 34474 ||  
        wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = 17)
  AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id

  GROUP BY ID, post_title, post_content, post_date 
  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 150
```

Now the problem is that i need to get only the today posts, so i add to this script this:

```
AND DATE(post_date) >= CURRENT_DATE
```

but after adding this, i see that many posts that are in some categories not only one, they are showed twice or more times.
Can some one help me to solve this issue?
Thank you

Please help.

Comment: Try to explain your database schema little bit more. Maybe you can try it with simpler query (`SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE DATE(post_date) >= CURRENT_DATE()`) and then add more conditions to find out which one is wrong.

Comment: i have the answer, thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `post_date` is part of your GROUP'ing, you should add the following right after the `GROUP BY` clause and before the `ORDER BY` clause (don't use it as a `WHERE` clause):

```
...
HAVING DATE(post_date) >= CURDATE()
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING DATE(post_date) >= CURDATE() ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 150' at line 15, this is the error i got.